# Space invaders game bug

Tags: python, pygame

I’ve posted part of a space invaders game before and now I’m much further in it. I’m new to programming so that’s why the code probably looks sloppy and I know it’s very inefficient but I don’t think I’m good enough to do any better at this point.

I have this weird problem. It happens in cycles of three before enemies move down I can’t hit any. Then they move down and I can hit only the second row then they move down again and I can only hit the first row and this keeps repeating. Here is all the code I have:

```
#-----!!!!SPACE INVADERS!!!!-----
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
#-----MAIN FUNCTIONS-----
def movement(move_x):
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT and x > 4:
            move_x = -5
        elif event.key == K_LEFT and x < 4:
            move_x = 0
        if event.key == K_RIGHT and x < (w-4):
            move_x = 5
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT and x > (w-4):
            move_x = 0
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            move_x = 0
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            move_x = 0
    return (move_x)

def SHOTS(shots,max_shot,x,shot_y,list_of_shots):
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if len(shots) < max_shot:
                    list_of_shots = [x-shot.get_width()/2,shot_y]
                    shots.append(list_of_shots)
    return (shots,list_of_shots)

def bullets(list_of_shots,shots):
    for list_of_shots in shots:
        if list_of_shots[1] <= 0:
            del shots[0]
    if len(shots) == 1:
        screen.blit(shot, shots[0])
    if len(shots) == 2:
        screen.blit(shot, shots[1])
        screen.blit(shot, shots[0])
    for i in shots:
        i[1] -= 15

def move_enemy(enemies,enemy_move,test_y,w,enemy_len):
    for i in enemies:
        enemy_len += 1
    for i in enemies[enemy_len-1]:
        if i == w-50:
            enemy_move = -.5
            test_y += .25
        elif i == (w-300):
            enemy_move = .5
            test_y += .25
    return (test_y,enemy_move)

def new_enemy(enemies,enemy_move,test_y,rep_test_y):
    for i in enemies:
        i[0] += enemy_move
        if test_y > rep_test_y:
            i[1] += 50
    return enemies

#-----FFRAME RAEE / SCREEN SIZE-----
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
w,h = 1200,800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

#-----SETTING IMAGES-----
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

ship = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
ship = pygame.transform.scale(ship,(100,50))
ship_top = screen.get_height() - ship.get_height()
ship_left = screen.get_width()/2 - ship.get_width()/2

screen.blit(ship, (ship_left,ship_top))

shot = pygame.image.load("SingleBullet.png")
shot = pygame.transform.scale(shot,(25,25))
shot_y = h-75

enemy = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
enemy = pygame.transform.scale(enemy, (50,50))
#-----GLOBAL VARIABLES-----
x = 0
delete_1 = 0
max_shot = 2
shots = []
list_of_shots = []
move_x = 0
enemy_y = 50
enemy_x = 0
enemies = []
enemy_move = 0
test_y = 0
rep_test_y = 0
number = 0
enemy_len = 0

#-----MAIN GAME LOOP-----
for i in range(20):
    enemies.append([enemy_x, enemy_y])
    if enemy_x >= w-300:
        enemy_x = -100
        enemy_y += 100
    enemy_x += 100

enemies.append([900,-h,])

while True:
    #----game settings----
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    #----setting images
    screen.blit(ship, (x-ship.get_width()/2,ship_top))                      #put ship in new postition
    for i in range(len(enemies)):
        screen.blit(enemy,enemies[i])                                       #put enemies in new position

    for event in pygame.event.get():                                        #system exit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        shots,list_of_shots = SHOTS(shots,max_shot,x,shot_y,list_of_shots)  #checks if shots have been fired and appends them to list of shots
    #----enemies-----
    rep_test_y = test_y
    test_y,enemy_move = move_enemy(enemies,enemy_move,test_y,w,enemy_len)             #makes the enemies move
    enemies = new_enemy(enemies,enemy_move,test_y,rep_test_y)
    #----movement / bullets----
    move_x = movement(move_x)                                               #move_x defines how much the ship moves and movement checks for and pres of arrow keys and move 5 pixles per check
    bullets(list_of_shots,shots)                                            #blits the bullets to the screen and checks if they are on the screen if they arnt then it removes from the list
    x+=move_x
    #----delets bullet----
    for i in enemies:
        number += 1
        for list_of_shots in shots:
            if list_of_shots[1] == (i[1] + 50):
                if list_of_shots[0] >= i[0] and list_of_shots[0] <= (i[0] +50):
                    del shots[0]
                    del enemies[number-1]
    number = 0

    #----update----
    pygame.display.update()                                                 #Updates screen
```

Comment: i plan on cleaning it up once i finish everything

Comment: Im getting alot of down votes can someone tell me why so i can make a better posts in the future

Comment: Please do not place things such as this previous comment into your questions. Even posting them as comments can be considered too chatty or non-constructive. I cleaned it up. Now the answer: I think that people don’t find your question helpful as it is hard to extract any useful information from a long code dump, partly because they don’t see effort on finding where the problem is. If you’re beginner in programming generally, it is not your fault, but you should learn how to debug your code ASAP and provide what you found in your questions. Maybe some of them will be solved before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with

```
if list_of_shots[1] == (i[1] + 50):
```

Sometimes it is true only for enemies in first row, sometimes for enemies in second row and sometimes it is false for all enemies.

Use

```
if abs( list_of_shots[1] - i[1] ) <= 50:
```

---

BTW:

In place of

```
for i in enemies:
    enemy_len += 1
for i in enemies[enemy_len-1]:
```

you can use

```
for i in enemies[-1]:
```

You could use `pygame.Rect()` for sprites position - than you could use `i.x` in place of`i[0]`. Or event `i.centerx`, `i.bottom`, `i.top`, etc. ([pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html))

---

I think you get so many downvote because your code is so messy. Use `class` with `pygame.Rect()` and than use pygame collision detection etc.

And use `I`, `can't`, `don't`, `I'm`, `I've` (etc.) in place of `i`, `cant`, `dont`, `Im`, `Ive`